# Difference between "bail on" and "scrap" in oral?

Tags: differences

In the australian context, I heard somebody said "scrap that" or "..bail on the van". Both basically mean "abandon, get rid of..", but was wondering what specific context shall I use them precisely, in terms of oral english.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a relatively new slang / colloquial use of ***to bail***. Until fairly recently the slang usage was normally reserved for the sense of ***leave, get away from***, but more recently (with a preposition such as ***on*** in your example) it's been extended to include the additional "negation" senses of ***cancel, reject*** for *some* speakers. The best advice for such usages is simply that you should only copy it yourself when with native Anglophones who you've already heard using the format.

Comment: OKay, I will. Thank you for your sharing, that helps a lot :)